# Kaggle website post method returning status code 400

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

While executing this block of code I am not able to get the data from Kaggle website as post method. It is ending with status_code 400:

```
#imports
import requests
requests import session
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

#payload for post
payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': os.environ.get("KAGGLE_USERNAME"),
    'password': os.environ.get("KAGGLE_PASSWORD")
}

print(payload)

#url for train file
url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv'

#setup session
with session() as c:
    #post request
    c.post('https://www.kaggle.com/account/login', data=payload)
    #get request
    response = c.get(url)
    #print response text
    print(response.text)
```